# Multiple Images in the Article, but Only 1 Image Is Showing in the SITEMAP

Tags: search-engine-indexing, sitemap, google-index, xml-sitemap, sitemap-index

there are multiple images in my posts but the sitemap is showing only 1 image, will it affect the indexing of my image in Google?

We use rank math plugin for sitemap.

How can I fix this
[image: here is the image]

Comment: The image posted does not show the relevant part of the sitemap for images.  Please post that portion as text

Comment: hello,
here is the sitemap link
https://dolphinwebsolution.com/sitemap_index.xml

Here is post sitemap where we are facing this issue
https://dolphinwebsolution.com/post-sitemap.xml

As you can see there are multiple images in the article but sitemap is showing only one image, which is effecting indexing of our images in google search.